# C# Listview column tag

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need to get the sender tag from the colums in a ListView, how can I do this?

I mean something like this:

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)        
{
   if((string)(sender as ColumnHeader).Tag == "...")
   {
      /*mycode*/
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting this here, but the answer `you can't ` is not correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833118/folderbrowsedialog-in-thread-c-sharp .  I would reopen it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender of the event is `ListView`. You should use `e.Column` which is the index of clicked column and find the column object, then get the value from tag

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    var column = listView1.Columns[e.Column];
    var tag = column.Tag as string;
    if(tag == "something")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for [`ColumnClickEventArgs.Column`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnclickeventargs.column(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns zero-based index of the column that is clicked.

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)        
{

   if(e.Column >=0 && ListView1.Columns[e.Column].Tag == "...")
   {
      /*mycode*/
   }
}
```